# Binary search of 2D matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, complexity, binary-search

I have written code as below:

```
bool binary_search(const std::vector<int>& v, const int& target) {
    int left = 0, right = v.size() - 1;

    while (left <= right) {
        int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;

        if (v[mid] == target)
            return true;

        if (target > v[mid])
            left = mid + 1;
        else
            right = mid - 1;
    }

    return false;
}

bool searchMatrix(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& matrix, int target) {
    const int n = matrix.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (target <= matrix[i][matrix[i].size() - 1])
            return binary_search(matrix[i], target);
    }

    return false;
}
```

It returns `true` if the target is found in `matrix`, and `false` when is not present.

The matrix has following properties:

1. Each row is sorted in non-decreasing order.
2. The first integer of each row is greater than the last integer of the previous row.

Due to these properties, the `binary_search` will be invoked only once.

The task was to create O(log(*mn*)) algorithm. But I'm pretty sure that this is O(*n* + log *m*).  So I'm looking to improve its computational complexity.

Comment: It looks like it’s O(n + log m). If you use a binary search to find the row, instead of the linear search you have now, you’ll get O(log nm).

Comment: Please present _complete_ code for review.  It's much easier if we don't have to infer your `#include`s and `main()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You clearly need to enable more compiler warnings.  For example, we want to know about the dangerous conversion in

```
int right = v.size() - 1;
```

Since `v.size()` returns a `std::size_t`, this is almost certainly a narrowing conversion, and may even give a negative value in `right`.

Your `binary_search()` function could be completely eliminated by using [`std::binary_search()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search) instead.  Don't reinvent wheels!

The linear search of rows (`for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)`) would be simpler using a range-based `for`.  But we don't want that - we should be using *binary search* to find the required row.

We should be passing a reference to **const** vector into `searchMatrix()`, since we don't intend to modify its values.

Comment: What about complexity? Can it be improved?

Comment: Yes - as said, use binary search rather than linear search when looking for rows.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I was reading in a hurry and somehow missed it